# Why does the swipe gesture recognizer give an error in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add the swipe gesture recognizer to the collection view by using swift. Everytime the user swipe to right or left, I want my collection view reload. However, when I swipe to right or left in collection view on the simulator, it gives me an error and AppDelegate.swift class is automatically opened. The error says **" libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException "**

I write this part to the viewDidLoad() in the collectionViewController class

```
    collectionView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    collectionView.delegate = self

    var left = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: collectionView, action: "swipping:")
    left.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(left)



    var right = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: collectionView, action: "swipping:")
    right.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(right)
```

This is the swipping function:

```
     func swipping (gesture : UIGestureRecognizer){
     if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
            collectionView.reloadData()
            pageControl.currentPage++


        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
            collectionView.reloadData()
            pageControl.currentPage--

        default:
            break
        }

    }
}
```

Added UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to the CollectionViewController class and AppDelegate class. What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare gesture recogniser you specify collectionView as a target:

```
var left = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: collectionView, action: "swipping:")
```

But I believe the swiping: method is placed in the same file where the declaration is taking place.
You have to change target to self:

```
 var left = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipping:")
 var right = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipping:")
```

//Extended

This is not working because UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView and when you swipe UIScrollView handle the gesture (this is because you can create collection in horizontal direction so collection view needs to know that you are scrolling left/right).

You should consider override UIScrollViewDelegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

to find out the swipe and you should handle it instead of adding gesture recogniser.

Try something like that:

```
//Declare private property
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat prevOffset

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
   if (self.prevOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.x)
      // You are swiping right
   else if (self.prevOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.x) 
      // You are swiping left

   self.prevOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;   
}
```

Comment: You are right, I changed it. Now it does not recognize when I swipe it to the left or right. It doesn't give an error, but again it does not work.

Comment: Please see extended answer.

Comment: I write the scrollViewDidScroll function as you said. However, it is never called. I mean when I want to print something in the scrollViewDidScroll method and run and scroll it, it did not print anything to the console.

Comment: It will work just when your UICollectionView content size is big enough to allow you scroll. If it isn't I afraid that this solution cannot help you.